# Google Website Optimizer & Adwords

Tags: google-website-optimizer

Right now I am running an A/B test through Google Website Optimizer(GWO). Adwords is used to link to a static version of a page that is not running in the test. I wanted to verify that if I set the destination url for adwords as my original page in the test that GWO will route traffic to my other test versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to verify that if I set the
>   destination url for adwords as my
>   original page in the test that GWO
>   will route traffic to my other test
>   versions.

Yes, traffic from adwords would be included in the test, which means visitors from adwords will randomly be assigned a test versions. In fact, **any** traffic to a a GWO test page will be included in the test.

Comment: Thanks Erik for clarifying on that.